# Generate a thumbnail of a Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, thumbnails

I have a website where users upload Word documents and I want to display thumbnails of these word documents. If anyone of you knows how to display the first page of a Word file as an image using C# please tell me.

Also if you know a trusted .NET library to convert word files to images that requires no office interop that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2009/06/12/windows-api-code-pack-for-microsoft-net-framework.aspx

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile);
Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```

It's Microsoft's API Code Pack

Comment: This solution only works if the you enable save thumbnail on word, otherwise it just returns the file logo.

Comment: @Hp93 Of course, otherwise you'd need to parse the document and render it!

Answer (score 1):

I found this question (7 yrs later) while searching for a similar solution. I'm evaluating [2JPEG](http://www.2jpeg.com/) and it appears to support [275 formats](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/list-of-supported-file-formats) including Word, Excel, Publisher & Powerpoint files. fCoder recommends running 2JPEG as a scheduled background task. The [command line syntax](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/2jpeg-command-line-syntax) is pretty comprehensive.

Here's a sample snippet to generate a thumbnail for a specific file:

```
2jpeg.exe -src "c:\files\myfile.docx" -dst "c:\files" -oper Resize size:"100 200" fmode:fit_width -options pages:"1" scansf:no overwrite:yes template:"{Title}_thumb.jpg" silent:yes
```

Answer (score 0):

A preview image of the 1st page of a .doc or .docx document can easily be created with **a tool called Free Spire.Doc for .NET** (a totally free word API for commercial and personal use). I found it to be fast and accurate.

Note from the developer's page:

*"The featured function, conversion allows converting Word documents (Word 97-2003, Word 2007, Word 2010, Word 2013, Word 2016 and Word 2019) to commonly used file format, such as XML, RTF, TXT, PDF, XPS, EPUB, HTML and Image etc.
Friendly Reminder:
**Free version is limited to 500 paragraphs and 25 tables**... "*

This C# code creates a System.Drawing.Image object of the 1st page of a .docx file:

```
using Spire.Doc

byte[] docContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\word_document.docx");

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(docContent))
{
    // Creates a Spire.Doc object to work with
    Spire.Doc.Document doc = new Spire.Doc.Document(ms, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Auto);
    // SaveToImages creates an array of System.Drawing.Image, we take only the 1st element
    System.Drawing.Image img = doc.SaveToImages(0, 1, Spire.Doc.Documents.ImageType.Bitmap)[0];
}
```

To create the thumbnail image, the following C# example includes a second *using* block to do it, and then converts to a base64 string:

```
using Spire.Doc

byte[] docContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\word_document.docx");

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(docContent))
{
    // Creates a Spire.Doc object to work with
    Spire.Doc.Document doc = new Spire.Doc.Document(ms, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Auto);
    // SaveToImages creates an array of System.Drawing.Image, we take only the 1st element
    System.Drawing.Image img = doc.SaveToImages(0, 1, Spire.Doc.Documents.ImageType.Bitmap)[0];

    using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Auxiliary object needed for GetThumbnailImage
        System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        // We create a thumbnail (0.5 width and height = 50%)
        img.GetThumbnailImage((int)(img.Width * 0.5), (int)(img.Height * 0.5), myCallback, IntPtr.Zero).Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        // Convert to Base64 string representation of the image
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms2.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In addition, the library can also convert in other ways, for instance this function returns .SVG files with each page:

```
doc.SaveToFile("resulting_file_name.svg", Spire.Doc.FileFormat.SVG);
```