# Create thumbnails of office documents

Tags: c#, ms-office, thumbnails

How can I create thumbnails (an image of the first page of the document) of office documents in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but there's possibly a thread of information you can follow here..

See [C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This answer should work for .doc and .docx files, at least:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445698/4783290

From the developer's page:

*"The featured function, conversion allows converting Word documents (Word 97-2003, Word 2007, Word 2010, Word 2013, Word 2016 and Word 2019) to commonly used file format, such as XML, RTF, TXT, PDF, XPS, EPUB, HTML and Image etc.
Friendly Reminder:
Free version is limited to 500 paragraphs and 25 tables... "*

Answer (score -1):

2JPEG is a great solution for generating thumbnails.  However, this only works in Microsoft Office files if you have Office installed in your computer.  It will not work in a server.

Comment: I don't have MS Office and it's generating proper images for doc and docx files anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I'm evaluating [2JPEG](http://www.2jpeg.com/) and it appears to support [275 formats](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/list-of-supported-file-formats) including Word, Excel, Publisher & Powerpoint files. fCoder recommends running 2JPEG as a scheduled background task. The [command line syntax](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/2jpeg-command-line-syntax) is pretty comprehensive.

Here's a sample snippet to generate a thumbnail for a specific file:

```
2jpeg.exe -src "c:\files\myfile.docx" -dst "c:\files" -oper Resize size:"100 200" fmode:fit_width -options pages:"1" scansf:no overwrite:yes template:"{Title}_thumb.jpg" silent:yes
```