# How to convert uploaded file into jpeg?

Tags: c#

I have a HTML page for user to upload file to sever.The file type can be image, pdf or word document. After user upload their file, it will show out on the HTML page similiar like gallery thumbnail, so that user can see it. For image it is easy, but how to do it with pdf or word document? For pdf or word document, I just need the first page of it..

Comment: Have a look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592112/generate-a-pdf-thumbnail-open-source-free) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009693/generate-a-thumbnail-of-a-word-document)

Comment: .NET itself doesn't have a method to do it, you'll need a framework. Check this link: http://sautinsoft.com/blog/?p=489